# Startup with GUI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gui

when i start ubuntu i get the command line, even if I run commands like

sudo service lightdm restart

and

sudo systemctl start lightdm

how can i return to have the desktop at startup?

Comment: What is the outout of `systemctl get-default`?

Comment: 'graphical.target'

Comment: Do you test `sudo systemctl enable lightdm` command ? I guess that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first step use this command:

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm
```

And reboot.

If it not works for you try to make lightdm your default disply manager:

```
echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" | sudo tee /etc/X11/default-display-manager > /dev/null
```

And reboot.

And if it's not work for you as the final step try this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Run these commands to install a desktop environment:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```